# placement new - buffer's value preserving

Tags: c++, gcc, placement-new

Is there a way to preserve original value of the buffer passed to placement new? Sample code:

```
struct MyStruct {
  int number;
  char bytes[100];
} __attribute__ ((packed));

char data[sizeof(MyStruct)]; // contains value received via TCP

MyStruct* create_struct_a() {
  char tmp[sizeof(MyStruct)];
  memcpy(tmp, data, sizeof(MyStruct));
  MyStruct* result = new (data) MyStruct;
  memcpy(result, tmp, sizeof(MyStruct));
  return result;
}

MyStruct* create_struct_b() {
  return new (data) MyStruct;
}
```

gcc 5.3 produces same asm code for both functions when MyStruct::bytes is small:

```
create_struct_a():
    movl    $data, %eax
    ret
create_struct_b():
    movl    $data, %eax
    ret
```

but when MyStruct::bytes size is larger than 150 gcc 5.3 produces:

```
create_struct_a():
    subq    $168, %rsp
    movl    $154, %edx
    movl    $data, %esi
    movq    %rsp, %rdi
    call    memcpy
    movq    %rsp, %rsi
    movl    $154, %edx
    movl    $data, %edi
    call    memcpy
    movl    $data, %eax
    addq    $168, %rsp
    ret
create_struct_b():
    movl    $data, %eax
    ret
```

I want the smaller asm code without memcpy for the larger structure, but can't find a legal way to force compiler to do this. `char data[sizeof(MyStruct)]` will be also used for storing other packed types with `size <= sizeof(MyStruct)` so data type should be `char[sizeof(MyStruct)]` not `MyStruct`.

Comment: If `data` is already a `MyStruct` instance (or rather, contains the memory of a valid `MyStruct` instance), and if `MyStruct` is a POD type, I think you can just `return reinterpret_cast<MyStruct*>(data);`.

Comment: No, `data` dynamic type depends on first bytes (header) of `data`. I can't use `return reinterpret_cast<MyStruct*>(data)` because `data` isn't a `MyStruct` instance.

Comment: But why not? You're just `memcpy`ing `data`'s bytes into the struct, and the compiled asm is equivalent to `reinterpret_cast<MyStruct*>(data)`.

Comment: Dereferencing `reinterpret_cast<MyStruct*>(data)` will be break strict-aliasing according to gcc's `warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]`

Comment: You are already looking at non-portable solutions here, considering that you are analyzing the object code emitted by a particular compiler. In that case, I do not understand why you are overly concerned with strict aliasing. Write the code you need to write it to produce the desired object code, ensure that it is semantically correct, and move on. Yes, it'll be a potential maintenance problem, but c'est la vie. Document it well with a comment, make sure you come back and analyze it when you upgrade compilers. Alternatively, change compilers now: Clang does exactly what you want for any size.